# Difference between `([^\<]+)<\/a>` and `(<a.+)<\/a>`?

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying not to capture anchor tags, so i used this

`(?!([^\<]+)<\/a>)(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])`

which excludes the anchor tag and selects the urls which are not present inside anchor tags but it fails for this case:

`<a href="www.google.com"> <b> Google Homepage </b> </a>` 
because of the left angular brace.

so I thought of using this

`(?!(<a.+)<\/a>)(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])` 
but this isn't working ?

Anybody please explain why this is not working and what can be the possible solution to my problem.

Hope I explained the question, thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: "what can be the possible solution to my problem" Don't use REGEX for something it's not suited for. Get a parser library for HTML and use that.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) answer that sums up all your problems with this approach, current and future.

Answer (score 1):

**Never** use Regex to parse html. Just don't. There are too many different complication, and using something like `htmlparser` is just way easier. This link should help you decide: https://tomassetti.me/parsing-html/ If you don't want to go to the link, here is the gist of the different parsers:

**Java**

- Lagarto and Jerry
- HtmlCleaner
- Jsoup

**C#**

- AngleSharp
- HtmlAgilityPack

**Python**

- HTML Parser of The Standard Library
- Html5lib
- Html5-parser
- Lxml
- AdvancedHTMLParser
- Beautiful Soup

**JavaScript**

- **Browser**

  - jQuery
  - DOMParser
- **Node.js**

  - Cheerio
  - Jsdom
  - Htmlparser2
  - Parse5

Comment: Nope, I'm not parsing the HTML it's just that I have a text input for which whenever a user enters a URL i want to convert it to clickable link and now the user thought of giving a name to those link using anchor tag, apart from this all other things are simple text.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
(a\shref=".+"|\/?b|Google Homepage|\/?a)
```

Comment: (a\shref=([a-z]|\.|\?|\"|)+|\/?b|([a-zA-Z]+)|\/?a)

Comment: can there be a general solution, this is specifically for <b> tag, there is a possibility of any other tag also. something by which I can say not select inside anchor tag (whatever there is, inside the tag). btw thanks for helping.

Comment: Oh, now I'm understand. Try this also if you want: ' > ([A-Za-z0-9 \. \? \! \ S] +) < '

Comment: Please don't advise people to use Regex to parse html. That's a trap. It might work for their very small, specific problem here, but when that is solved they will just stumble into the next and then the next and then the next. Suggest a proper solution instead (or at least on top).

Comment: I made a different answer if that helps @nvoigt